# How to change name in context menu dynamicaly by a condition

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I am using this contextmenu plugin for jQuery:

> http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/trigger-left-click.html.

and I am trying to change the name of a menu item dynamically by a simple condition. Unfortunately it isn't possible to change a menu item's name dynamically or I don't know how to do so...

I tried it this way:

```
   items: {
           "item": {name: (x > 10) ? 'name1' : 'name2', disabled: false},
           "sep1": "----------------",
           ....
   }
```

but it isn't working.
Then I tried it with an anonymous function:

```
 items: {
         "item": {name: function(){ return (x > 10) ? 'name1' : 'name2'; }, disabled: false},
         "sep1": "----------------",
         ....
 }
```

but it isn't working as well...
Now I have no other clue, so I am asking you for help.
Do you have useful advice for me?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you getting when you `console.log(x)`?

Comment: x is just a variable which holds a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name will be defined at the beginning, not every click. If you wanna redefine the item name every time you should do it like this:

```js
var x = 0;
$(function() {
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
      var m = "clicked: " + key;
    },
    items: {
      "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
      "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
      copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
      "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
      "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
      "sep1": "---------",
      "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
        return 'icon icon-quit';
      }}
    }
  });

  $('.context-menu-one').on('contextmenu', function(e){
    $('.icon-edit span').text('x: ' + x);
    x++;
  });    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="context-menu-one btn btn-neutral">right click me</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need but my context menu has no icons. Can I select the menu item only by its id or its name? E.g. in my code listing the menu item is called 'item'. Can I select it by the name 'item'?

Comment: you can use the inspector (f12 in chrome) to find out how to select it ... use ".context-menu-item span" and it will work fine

Comment: I did it this way: 
     `$('.context-menu-one').on('contextmenu', function(e){
         $('ul li:nth-child(3)').text((x > 10) ? 'name1' : 'name2');
     });` @rafaelcastrocouto Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 7):

I think you should use the build option. This makes it possible to build the menu at runtime, so it can evaluate the expression before showing the menu.

http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#build

```
$.contextMenu({
selector: 'span.context-menu',
build: function($triggerElement, e){
    var conditionalName = (x > 10) ? 'name1' : 'name2';
    return {
        callback: function(){},
        items: {
            menuItem: {name: conditionalName}
        }
    };
}
```

});

Comment: That is a nice solution, too. Thanks a lot @Bjorn.